# startProfile(FirefoxProfile, File, String) undefined for the type FirefoxBinary

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-profile

Is the method `startProfile(FirefoxProfile, File, String)` in `FirefoxBinary` deprecated ?

I have imported the latest selenium jar in my java project and I am having a compiling error when I'm trying to use `startProfile(FirefoxProfile, File, String)`. It says : The method is undefined for the type FirefoxBinary. My code looks like this :

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(myProfileDir);
profile.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
try { 
        binary.startProfile(profile, myProfileDir, ""); 

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

And when I look at the type hierarchy of the `jar` file, there is no `startProfile(FirefoxProfile, File, String)` method in the `FirefoxBinary` class.

Is there a way to solve this problem, or is there an other method that does the trick ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest selenium standalone server jar ? If so, try the previous releases and choose the selenium server zip. Make sure you include all the jars in your build path.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of [startProfile](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.html#startProfile-org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile-java.io.File-java.lang.String...-) is `String...`, i.e. `varargs`. If you don't want any parameter there just don't send any

```
binary.startProfile(profile, myProfileDir);
```